# Pickle file with many objects

Tags: python, pickle

I cannot get my file to store multiple instances of contacts. After adding new contact and trying to print them, it comes up with "IndexError: list index out of range" error. What shall I do to make it work?

```
import pickle

class People():
    def __init__(self, name, surname, age, mobile_no, home_no):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age
        self.mobile_no = mobile_no
        self.home_no = home_no

    def DisplayContacts(self):
        print("First Name: \t", self.name)
        print("Surname: \t", self.surname)
        print("Age: \t", self.age)
        print("Mobile Number: \t", self.mobile_no)
        print("Home Number: \t", self.home_no)
        print()


def addContact():
    newname = str(input("First name: \t"))
    newsurname = str(input("Surname: \t"))
    newage = int(input("Age: \t"))
    newmobile_no = int(input("Mobile Number: \t"))
    newhome_no = int(input("Home Number: \t"))
    newContact = People(newname, newsurname, newage, newmobile_no, newhome_no) 
    return newContact

cont = 1

contacts = []


while cont == 1:
    user = input("Do you want to add contact? (Y/N)")
    if user == "Y" or user == "y":
        print ("works")
        contacts.append(addContact())
        file = open("CList.pickle", "ab")
        pickle.dump(contacts, file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        file.close()
    else:
        print ("111")
        cont = 0


useropen = input("open file? (Y/N)")
if useropen == "Y" or useropen == "y":


    with open ("CList.pickle", "rb") as pickled_file:
        contacts = pickle.load(pickled_file)
        print(contacts[0].surname)
        print(contacts[1].surname)


else:
    print("Null")
```

Comment: Looks like each time you make a new contact, you open the file and append the pickled object to the existing data there. Are you sure that's allowed? I don't think `pickle.dumps(a) + pickle.dumps(b)` is the same as `pickle.dumps([a,b])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply appending a picked object to a file is not the same thing as pickling a list. EAch time you append, you've created another pickled record. Read the file multiple times to get your list:

```
with open ("CList.pickle", "rb") as pickled_file:
    contacts = []
    try:
        while True:
            contacts.append(pickle.load(pickled_file))
    except EOFError:
            pass
```

Now, instead of appending the list of contacts (which would give you a list of lists with many duplicates), just pickle the new contact:

```
with open("CList.pickle", "ab") as _file:
    while True:
        user = input("Do you want to add contact? (Y/N)")
        if user == "Y" or user == "y":
            print ("works")
            pickle.dump(addContact(), _file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        else:
            print ("111")
            break
```

Comment: @JoeDoe - have you changed the object you are pickling? You could have old cruft in the file - deleting and starting over may help. I also realized I didn't note that you should change how you pickle also... just pickle the contact object, not the list of contact objects. I am making an update to the anwser.

Comment: I did all as you suggested but when I try to load the file it's just a empty prompt

Comment: I ran the patched up code and found that dump/load aren't quite symatric. You end up with an extra new line, so the loop that reads the records gets Person, None, Person, None, ... Solving this is mildly annoying, you could for instance prepend each write with the length of the thing you are writing, or more easily just skip the Nones.

Comment: and what would be the way to skip those?

Comment: One option is to load into a variable and then check if its None before adding to the list. Another is to build up your own records using ctypes. Pickle into a string and then use ctypes to write a record of length,pickled_string. The reader would read length-ed chunks.